# Typecasting with shorthand operators

Tags: java

```
byte b=12;

b >>= 2; // Why is this legal? why does it automatically typecasts?

b = b >> 2; // Why is this illegal if the above is legal
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b>>=2;`
is same as
`b = (byte) (b>> 2);`

---

[**15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2)

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

Comment: Yeah, but here you have to explicitly cast into a byte, while with shorthand operators you don't. Are there any rules associated with shorthand operators that allow this to be done implicitly.