# Meaning of += sign

Tags: javascript

I am not a Javascript expert and I need a little help.
What does += means in javascript?
[Random color generator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript)
In the link above, the top voted comment shows a way of having a random color, I tried to figure out what the code means but I don't know what the sign "+=" stands for.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: [Shorthand Assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) Same as `a = a + b;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short hand assignment operator, +=, True Meaning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362017/short-hand-assignment-operator-true-meaning)

Comment: @Saif That's a Java question.

Comment: @Saif That's Java, OP is asking about Java**Script**

Comment: shorthand concept is same for all language, isn't it?

Comment: @Saif: It's not useful to do anything even vaguely promoting the ongoing confusion between Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` is the concatenation equals operator. Often used to append and assign strings;

```
var s = 'Hello';
s += ' World';

console.log(s); // Hello World
```

Comment: *"+= is the concatenation equals operator"* It *can* be. It's also the addition-equals operator. Depends on the operands.